# exception while calling accept()

Tags: c++, windows

```cpp
//this is server side code snippet used for chat application 

int* sockPtr;
int result;
result=listen(sClient,10); //sClient is SOCKET that is bind to specific port for  listining incoming connection 
sockPtr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));        
*sockPtr= accept(sClient,(SOCKADDR*)&client_info,&addrlen); //here is the problem on sockPtr [which is integer type pointer]
```

but when a client try to connect there is an exception saying

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0041ce6b in server.exe: 0xC0000005:
Access violation reading location 0x0000000.
```

What shall I do?

Comment: i suggest you check all arguments and return codes from functions to see if they are all OK.

Answer (score 2):

when calling `accept()`, the second parameter is a buffer you provide to store the address informations, which depends on the address family of the socket you are listening for.

so, the buffer specified in the second parameter have to be declared and allocated before calling the `accept()`, and the third parameter should contain the allocated size for the buffer. the function will then fill the buffer and return the actual length of the buffer which was filled by the requested informations.

something like:

```
struct sockaddr_in client_info;
int                client_info_length;
[...]

client_info_length = sizeof(client_info);
*sockPtr= accept(sClient,(SOCKADDR*)&client_info,&client_info_length);
```

the `struct sockaddr_in` structure stores an address for an "internet" address family (TCP/IP). if you are using another protocol (which i doubt...), use the appropriate structure.

Comment: i meant `struct sockaddr_in`, since there is no typedef you absolutely need this `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

`Access violation reading location 0x0000000` means you got a nullpointer access. Either `malloc` returns a nullpointer since you're out of memory, or you the problem lies somewhere else. I don't know much about socket programming, but that `*sockPtr= accept(...)` looks suspicios.